# Как написать правильный .bind()?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Хочу отследить замену класса. Суть в том, что класс меняется при скролле, когда скролю вниз - работает норм, но когда скролю вверх, то `.bind()` не срабатывает. Что я делаю не так, подскажите

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var originalAddClassMethod = jQuery.fn.addClass;
var originalRemoveClassMethod = jQuery.fn.removeClass;
jQuery.fn.addClass = function(){
    var result = originalAddClassMethod.apply( this, arguments );
    jQuery(this).trigger('classChanged');
    return result;
};
jQuery.fn.removeClass = function(){
    var result = originalRemoveClassMethod.apply( this, arguments );
    jQuery(this).trigger('classChanged');
    return result;
};

$('.header__cart').bind('classChanged', function(){
    // var headerCart = $('.default-cart');
    // headerCart.mouseenter(mouseInCart);
    // headerCart.mouseleave(mouseOutCart);

    console.log('123');

    if($(this).hasClass('default-cart')){
        console.log('456');
        // this.mouseenter(mouseInCart);
        // this.mouseleave(mouseOutCart);
        $(this).mouseenter(function(){
            $('.default-cart > .title').fadeOut(0);
            $('.default-cart > .img').fadeOut(0);
            $('.default-cart > .sum').fadeOut(0);
            $('.default-cart > .content').fadeIn(200);
            $('.default-cart > .button').fadeIn(0);
        });
        $(this).mouseleave(function(){
            $('.default-cart > .content').fadeOut(0);
            $('.default-cart > .button').fadeOut(0);
            $('.default-cart > .title').fadeIn(200);
            $('.default-cart > .img').fadeIn(200);
            $('.default-cart > .sum').fadeIn(200);
        })
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('fixed-cart')){
        console.log('789');
        $('.fixed-cart > .title').fadeOut(0);
        $('.fixed-cart > .img').fadeOut(0);
        $('.fixed-cart > .sum').fadeOut(0);
        $('.fixed-cart > .content').fadeOut(0);
        $('.fixed-cart > .button').fadeOut(0);
    }

});
});
```

Comment: .bind() has been deprecated. It was superseded by the .on(). думаю перевод не нужен )  используйте .on()

Comment: Функция отрабатывает одинаково с `bind()` и `on()` в моей ситуации